# Fortran storing concatenated string

Tags: fortran

I have a simple program:

```
PROGRAM concatenate

CHARACTER::char*11,name*4

CHARACTER(20)::charname

char='hello there'
name='Fred'

WRITE(*,*) char

WRITE(*,*) name

charname = char // ', ' // name

WRITE(*,*) charname

END PROGRAM
```

Let's say that I didn't want to specify the length of the variable charname in advance, so that its length is automatically determined by the length of char and name. Can I do that in Fortran?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could declare `charname` like this:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: charname
```

and the compiler/run-time will take care of making `charname` the right length when you assign a value to it

```
charname = char//','//name
```

You can even automatically re-allocate it with another statement such as

```
charname = char//', Mr'//name
```

This all depends on your compiler having implemented these features of Fortran 2003 but all the latest versions of the widely used compilers have.

Comment: Cheers Mark, very helpful. So is this character allocatable feature part of the F2003 standard, or can it also be used in F90/95?